# Twitter bootstrap minimum width in responsive layout

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way to tell bootstrap to not shrink the elements when the resolution is smaller than:

```
/* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */.
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) { ... }
```

I want to support the large desktops and tablets screen, but nothing responsive below that resolution.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can add the css property [`min-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/min-width) on all the elements you want not to be shrunk.

Comment: This is not the right solution... you should disable the low-resolution responsive code as per the below two suggestions.

Comment: And if I want to get a specific value, like `min-width: 598px;`? I think this is a simple and fast workaround.

Answer (score 17):

Adding the min-width property wont stop the grid system from messing up though, as the classes span1-12 will still become smaller when resizing!

An option is visit http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html and untick "Narrow tablets and below (<767px)" on the responsive section, then download your custom bootstrap.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove media query code of mobile screen in bootstrap.css

Answer (score 1):

I did two steps

1. set less variable `@screen-sm-min: 10px`. This will stop all bootstrap's media query
2. And just set `min-width` to the top element.

Works for me