# stopping bootstrap template from shrinking after a certain point

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been wondering if there is a way to stop bootstrap from shriking after a certain point. I like the way my website looks 700 px width. so is there a way to stop bootstrap from shirking my html after that point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that, as mentioned in question [Twitter bootstrap minimum width in responsive layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13716562/twitter-bootstrap-minimum-width-in-responsive-layout), you can set `min-width` CSS property to `700px` for any element you don't want to be narrower than 700px.

Say you have a div called "wrapper" that wraps all of your page contents:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <!-- All contents in here -->
</div>
```

You can style it like this:

```
#wrapper {
    min-width: 700px;
}
```

**NOTE**: If you are using responsive layout, you will also have to comment the styles you want to be disabled in `bootstrap-responsive.css` file.

So, when using responsive layout, if you want your site to be displayed 700px wide, you will also have to comment the styles under:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
@media (max-width: 480px) {
@media (max-width: 979px) {
@media (min-width: 980px) {
```

And leave the CSS rules (but removing the @media and the brackets) of styles under:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: the only problem with the solution is that the child elements dont stop shrinking though

Comment: is there an easier way to stop child elements from shrinking other than explicitly defining min-width property for each of them?

Comment: If you set the min-width of the most external element (say "body" tag or a "div" wrapper-like tag), inner elements should not be narrower than that min-width... (see http://jsfiddle.net/aQTDd/1/) Could you provide an example?  Maybe Bootstrap does some weird stuff, but I believe it shouldn't.

Comment: I've added max-width to my main container, but the [media](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#media) divs inside the main div still scale.

Comment: In case you are using responsive layout (`bootstrap-responsive.css`), I edited my answer.  Hope that's handy for you.

Comment: so basically I would have to go and edit the bootstrap-responsive file? there is no other way around?

Comment: At least there is none that I know, :-(

Comment: Yeah I guess thats the only option. I ended up using your suggested method